# What did Ser Alliser mean?

Tags: game-of-thrones

At the beginning of the conversation of Ser Alliser Thorne and

> Jon Snow

Ser Alliser called him The

> Lord Commander of the Night's Watch

He then says that he made a choice, and if he do it all over again, he pray he make the right choice again. He then go on to explain that he fought and he lost and now he will rest but

> Lord Snow, you

will be fighting forever.

Knowing the type of person he is, I assume he has no regrets of what he did and he will do it again. That explains the first line.

But, why he called him Lord

> Snow instead of Lord Commander?

and what he meant by 'fighting forever'? Is it just a dying man's empty curse?

Comment: Ser Alliser fought and lost for mad king Aerys as well, which is why he is at the wall.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thorne calls Jon, "Lord Snow" to mock him. He has been calling Jon that since their first interaction at the wall. Jon is bastard but was raised in a noble house at his father's (Eddard) side. Jon could never be a "Lord" since he was a Snow and not a Stark.

Thorne is much like a drill instructor, he is trying to get under the skin of ALL the new recruits in the Night's Watch to toughen them up get them used to the harsh ways at the wall.

The nickname "Lord Snow" stuck because it seemed to get under Jon's skin. Thorne had no love for Jon, so he uses his last words to get a final jab in.

See in the video at the 0:15 mark.

---

What Thorne meant by "fighting forever" is a little more open for interpretation...

1. Fighting the White Walkers
2. Fighting the Wildlings
3. Fighting brothers of the Watch that do not see eye-to-eye

Overall, Thorne is probably trying to convey that Jon will always have enemies that want to kill him.